# Probability that $2$ letters will show up before $2$ others in $22$ different letters.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question says:

We write $22$ different letters $x_1,x_2,...,x_{22}$ Randomly each must show up but only once.

What is the probability that $x_1,x_2$ Will show up before $x_3,x_4$?

The letters don’t have to show up one near the other.

---

What i think:

So the probability is of the sense $\frac{x}{22!}$

Now for the $x$, to choose the place of $x_1,x_2$ We have $20 \cdot 19$ possibilities(They cant be at the two last places, which will surely cause that $x_3,x_4$ Will come before and not after $x_1,x_2$). Now, the number of possibilities to choose the place for $x_3,x_4$ Is depended upon the place we chose $x_1,x_2$ At - Here i am stuck.

Can someone give me a hint please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the favorable cases, choose four positions for the numbers in question.  If $x_1$ and $x_2$ must both appear before $x_3$ and $x_4$, they must be in the first two of these positions, while $x_3$ and $x_4$ must appear in the last two of these positions.  In how many ways can this occur?  In how many ways can the remaining $18$ letters be arranged in the remaining $18$ positions?

Comment: Let me try, choose 4 places so $\binom{22}{4}$ now the probability that in those 4 places $x_1,x_2$ Will come before is $0.5$, and the rest of the letters organize randomly - its $18!$ - so totally we get: $\frac{\binom{22}{4} \cdot 0.5 \cdot 18!}{22!}$ Yet i still don’t get an answer that is correct.

Comment: Not quite.  There are $\binom{22}{4}$ ways to select positions for the four numbers.  There are $2!$ ways to arrange $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the first two of these four positions and $2!$ ways to arrange $x_3$ and $x_4$ in the last two of these four positions.  The remaining numbers can be arranged in the remaining $18$ positions in $18!$ ways.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is $\binom{22}{4}2!2!18!$.

Comment: Oh i was wrong in the order of the $4$.... Yes, now it makes sense, thank you for your guide.